# How to rearranged items in an inventory

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a game in AS3. 
The player can grabb items and add it to his inventory in a line. 
Everything is working, but I've got a bug when the player use an item wich is in the middle of the line. 
It doesen't rearanged well..
(here is a video if I'm not very clear : http://ul.to/z7su5dqm or here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5-MjJcEPm3lTTlDV09MYWxMOFE/edit?usp=sharing)

I've got the code that add the item to the inventory :

```
public function addInvItem(itemName:String):void{
            var itemRef:Object = getDefinitionByName(itemName.toLowerCase()+"Inv");
            var addedItem:MovieClip = new itemRef;
            addedItem.displayName = itemName;
            if (playerItems.length < 8){ // This is for the top row of up to 4 items
                addedItem.y = 520;
                addedItem.x = 60 + (playerItems.length) * 100;
            }
            if (isUnique(addedItem)){
                this.addChild(addedItem);
                playerItems.push(addedItem); 
                allItems.push(addedItem); 
                addedItem.buttonMode = true;
                addedItem.invItem = true;
                addedItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useItem, false, 0, true);
                puzzle = Engine.puzzle;
                puzzle.gotItem(addedItem.displayName);
            }
```

So the first item is add at `x= 60 and y = 520.`

And then I've got this code in order to remove and rearranged the items :

```
public function removeInvItem(itemName:String):void{
            removedItem = itemName;
            var itemNum:int;
            for (var i in playerItems){
                if (playerItems[i].displayName == itemName){
                    playerItems[i].visible = false;
                    itemNum = i;
                } else {
                    playerItems[i].visible = true;
                }
            }
            playerItems = playerItems.filter(checkForItem);

            // Rearrange the rest of the items
            for (i in playerItems){
                if (i >= itemNum){
                        playerItems[i].x -= 100;


                    }
                }

        }
```

Do you see where could be the error that push my first item ? (I suppose it came from `playerItems[i].x -= 100`). 
I must find a way to tell the code that first item can't be less than `x = 60` but the other must move `x= -100` everytime their are used...

Any idea how I can do that ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: First lots of hardcoded values, second you should rearrange items which means positioning it from the new starting point - and not by substracting X pixels. In other words if playerItems contains only visible items that should be rearranged I would do for each: get starting position for inventory as newx and newx, position item using newx and newy, update newx and newy with appropriate values (e.g. height and gap between items) also most likely you will update only newy for vertical spread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in assuming `playerItems[i].x -= 100;` is where the problem is caused. You are subtracting the current x position without any checks for if that falls over your inventory icon asset.

You could do something like this instead:

```
public function removeInvItem(itemName:String):void{
    removedItem = itemName;
    var itemNum:int;
    for (var i in playerItems){
        if (playerItems[i].displayName == itemName){
            playerItems[i].visible = false;
            itemNum = i;
        } else {
            playerItems[i].visible = true;
        }
    }
    adjustInventory( itemNum );
}

public function adjustInventory( itemNum:int ):void {
    var i:int;
    for ( i=itemNum; i < playerItems.length; i++ ) {
        //you can replace 60 with inventoryIcon.x + inventoryIcon.width instead
        playerItems[i].x -= playerItems[i].x - 100 >= 60 ? 100 : playerItems[i].x - 60;
    }
}
```

This evaluates the distance you are about to move before you do it, and only moves the necessary inventory items. I haven't tested this code but this should put you on the right path.